# casting issues in C PHP extension

Tags: php, c

I am trying to building a PHP extension for the Exponential Moving Average algorithm.
I'm new to C and i believe i have some casting issues (see commented line in code below).

Expected result : 622.81176945058

Actual result : 7.9131985629043E-316

Code:

```
double computeLastEMA(HashTable *arr_hash, double period)
{
    zval **data;
    HashPosition pointer;
    double k, n;
    int i = 0;

    k = 2.0 / ((double) period + 1.0 );

    // Compute Simple Moving Average
    for(zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(arr_hash, &pointer);
            zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(arr_hash, (void **) &data, &pointer) == SUCCESS && i < period;
            zend_hash_move_forward_ex(arr_hash, &pointer), ++i
    ) {
            n += *(double *) data;
    }

    n = n / period;

    // Compute Exponential Moving Average
    for(;
            zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(arr_hash, (void **) &data, &pointer) == SUCCESS;
            zend_hash_move_forward_ex(arr_hash, &pointer)
    ) {
            n += k * ( *(double *) data - n );
            i = *(double *) data; // !this is the casting issue!
    }

    return i;
}

PHP_FUNCTION(lastEMA)
{
    zval *values;
    HashTable *arr_hash;
    long period;

    if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "a|l", &values, &period) == FAILURE)
    {
            RETURN_NULL();
    }

    arr_hash = Z_ARRVAL_P(values);

    RETURN_DOUBLE(computeLastEMA(arr_hash, period));
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks!
(In fact i have no idea what the '*' mean exactly! :( )

Comment: @redFIVE I know quite a few languages already, i'm just not used to low-level ones like C. Your comment brings nothing to this conversation since i'm just asking to learn from my mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each element in the array is a double value, you need to cast the `zval **` to a `double` value using [`Z_DVAL_PP(data)`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/Zend/zend_operators.h#475).

```
for(zend_hash_internal_pointer_reset_ex(arr_hash, &pointer);
            zend_hash_get_current_data_ex(arr_hash, (void **) &data, &pointer) == SUCCESS && i < period;
            zend_hash_move_forward_ex(arr_hash, &pointer), ++i
    ) {
        double value = Z_DVAL_PP(data);
        n += value;
    }
```

The other loop can be fixed in the same way.

Lastly, you can use the `H` type in zpp to simplify the code:

```
HashTable *arr_hash;
double period = 0.f;

if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "H|d", & arr_hash, &period) == FAILURE)
{
    RETURN_NULL();
}
```

I've also fixed a potential type issue in the optional `period` parameter.